# Multiple Dir serving is not working

Tags: go

Any mistakes in below code? Multiple directory serving is not working from the below code. When I access the localhost:9090/ide, the server will return 404 error.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func serveIDE(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/user/ide")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func serveConsole(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/user/console")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ide", serveIDE)         
    http.HandleFunc("/console", serveConsole) 
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)  
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

When I change the code like this,

```
http.HandleFunc("/", serveIDE)
```

It will work as I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the issues with using `http.FileServer` is that the request path is used to build the file name, so if you're serving from anywhere but the root you need to strip the route prefix to that handler.

The standard library includes a helpful tool for that `http.StripPrefix`, but that only works on `http.Handler`s, not `http.HandleFunc`s, so to use it you need to adapt your `HandleFunc` to a `Handler`.

Here is a working version that should do what you want. Note that wHandler is just an adapter from your `HttpFunc` methods to `Hander` interface:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func serveIDE(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/user/ide")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func serveConsole(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/user/console")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

type wHandler struct {
        fn http.HandlerFunc
}

func (h *wHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("Handle request: %s %s", r.Method, r.RequestURI)
        defer log.Printf("Done with request: %s %s", r.Method, r.RequestURI)
        h.fn(w, r)
}

func main() {
        http.Handle("/ide", http.StripPrefix("/ide", &wHandler{fn: serveIDE}))
        http.Handle("/console", http.StripPrefix("/console", &wHandler{fn: serveConsole}))
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
        }
}
```